# CHAINLINK NODE - Start up Issues - Unable to Initialize ORM

Tags: postgresql, chainlink

Trying to start my node and having errors. Below is the error message. For reference: Using GCP, Ubuntu, Postgres Public db, Docker 0.9.4, and Infura. Replaced my password with PASSWORD in error message, but was entered correctly during testing. I'm close, I believe, just need some help getting over this final hurdle.  Thank you!

```
cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.9.4 local n
2021-07-12T20:46:51Z [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 0.9.4 at commit b7d22afdae61fc9146136e8518c221d406d10d6d cmd/local_client.go:51
2021-07-12T20:46:51Z [INFO]  Locking postgres for exclusive access with 500ms timeout orm/orm.go:69
2021-07-12T20:49:01Z [ERROR] unable to lock ORM: dial tcp 35.222.48.64:5432: connect: connection timed out logger/default.go:155   stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Errorf
        /chainlink/core/logger/default.go:155
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.(*ORM).MustEnsureAdvisoryLock
        /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:91
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.NewORM
        /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:75
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.initializeORM
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:176
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.newStoreWithKeyStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:78
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.NewStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:57
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:97
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.ChainlinkAppFactory.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/cmd/client.go:84
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:53
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:526
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:174
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:407
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:373
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:279
main.Run
        /chainlink/core/main.go:18
main.main
        /chainlink/core/main.go:12
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204
2021-07-12T20:51:12Z [FATAL] Unable to initialize ORM: dial tcp 35.222.48.64:5432: connect: connection timed out
unable to open postgresql://chainlink-db-user:PASSWORD@35.222.48.64:5432/chainlink-kovan-db for gorm DB
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.Connection.initializeDatabase
        /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:1618
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.NewORM
        /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:77
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.initializeORM
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:176
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.newStoreWithKeyStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:78
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.NewStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:57
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:97
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.ChainlinkAppFactory.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/cmd/client.go:84
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:53
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:526
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:174
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:407
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:373
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:279
main.Run
        /chainlink/core/main.go:18
main.main
        /chainlink/core/main.go:12
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
unable to init DB
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.NewORM
        /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:79
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.initializeORM
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:176
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.newStoreWithKeyStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:78
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.NewStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:57
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:97
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.ChainlinkAppFactory.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/cmd/client.go:84
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:53
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:526
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:174
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:407
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:373
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:279
main.Run
        /chainlink/core/main.go:18
main.main
        /chainlink/core/main.go:12
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
initializeORM#NewORM
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.initializeORM
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:178
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.newStoreWithKeyStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:78
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.NewStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:57
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:97
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.ChainlinkAppFactory.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/cmd/client.go:84
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:53
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:526
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:174
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:407
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:373
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:279
main.Run
        /chainlink/core/main.go:18
main.main
        /chainlink/core/main.go:12
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 store/store.go:80       stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.newStoreWithKeyStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:80
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.NewStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:57
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:97
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.ChainlinkAppFactory.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/cmd/client.go:84
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:53
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:526
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:174
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:407
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:373
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:279
main.Run
        /chainlink/core/main.go:18
main.main
        /chainlink/core/main.go:12
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your virtual machine for the Chainlink node (Ubuntu) and your PostgreSQL server with its database hosted in the same virtual private cloud on GCP, then it is recommended to take out the public IP of the postgres server and create an internal IP. You can change this in the postgres settings under "Connections". Then add this private IP (`10.x.x.x`) to your `DATABASE_URL` config in your environmental file. The Chainlink node should now be able to establish a connection. Please ensure that you remove the Chainlink node before a reinitialisation.

1. You can check all current containers (including the killed ones) with :`docker ps -a`
2. kill a container with: `docker kill <container-name>`
3. remove a container with: `docker rm <container-name>`

Then finally just reinitialize the node with your run command.

Comment: Hi Rob. I was able to create the Private IP and connect. However I must not have removed the chainlink node before reinitialization.  Do I need to kill or remove all the old docker containers, then execute the run command again?  Below is the error code that was continuously looping:

Comment: [ERROR] HeadTracker: dropping head 26085153 with hash 0xf50e19099b7e343829935d70dd7d86c5bc0398286b7a4e4f32ac033ac60c3733 because queue is full. WARNING: Your node is overloaded and may start missing jobs. logger/default.go:155   stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Errorf

Comment: This [ERROR] log is related to your blockchain connection. The cause is the high amount of interactions with the full node, based on requests every single block. Have a look on your full node or change the third party NaaS provider or the tier, will fix this issue. It will be awesome if you create a new Stackoverflow question where i can give you a more detailed answer related to the blockchain connection, because it will may add a lot of value to other people too!